# Measure width and height of a layout larger than the screen

Tags: android

How do we get the width and height of a layout (Eg. `LinearLayout`) if its width and height is larger than the screen?

I can only get the size that is as big as the screen using `getWidth()` and `getHeight()`.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this issue ? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this-

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.your_activity, null);  
LinearLayout linearlayout = (LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.yourlinearlayout);  
linearlayout.measure(0,0);  
int width = linearlayout.getMeasuredWidth();    
int height = linearlayout.getMeasuredHeight();
```

Comment: Answer by yuva is for measuring device dimensions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me... When my view is wider than the screen, returns the width of the screen. Anybody has a solution ? Thanks